# Mongodb failed after reboot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi

I've successfully installed mongodb with the following install script on my raspberry pi https://github.com/svvitale/mongo4pi/blob/master/install.sh. I've tested it and got a connection to the test database via `mongo` and everything worked well. I've rebooted my raspberry (B) and noticed, that mongod failed to start on reboot. After all i tried to start `mongod` manually but got the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi /opt/mongo/bin $ ./mongod
db level locking enabled: 1
./mongod --help for help and startup options
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44   Assertion failure 5 == (int)(g.distance( a , b ) ) src/mongo/db/geo/2d.cpp 3111
0x315e08 0x2015b4 0x393554 0x441d84 0x397f80 0x15c1d0 0xb6c7381c
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x18) [0x315e08]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo12sayDbContextEPKc+0xc4) [0x2015b4]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x108) [0x393554]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo11GeoUnitTest3runEv+0x3b84) [0x441d84]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo11StartupTest8runTestsEv+0x44) [0x397f80]
 ./mongod(main+0x1f58) [0x15c1d0]
 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x110) [0xb6c7381c]
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44 terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
0x315e08 0x16f708 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0 0xb6e92fb0
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x18) [0x315e08]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo11myterminateEv+0x40) [0x16f708]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6(+0x4efb0) [0xb6e92fb0]
Wed Jul  1 23:26:44 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Wed Jul  1 23:26:44 Backtrace:
0x315e08 0x1703bc 0xb6c89b20 0xb6c888dc
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x18) [0x315e08]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x240) [0x1703bc]
 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0xb6c89b20]
 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x40) [0xb6c888dc]
```

Do you guys have any idea what went wrong during the reboot?

thanks!

Comment: Exactly same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and removing the lock file /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock worked for me

Comment: This works because you didn't shutdown mongod properly and the mongod.lock file said so. Deleting the file allows it to be regenerated. I haven't seen any damage to data doing this, personally.

Comment: I'd like to plus-one the  comment above though, as I've just experienced this on the pi (my previous comment is from experience using MongoDB on Windows) ..

I just saw this when I ran `me@mine /opt/mongo/bin $ ./mongod --repair`. I'm more concerned about `Assertion failure 5..`. If I had enough points for a bounty..